# How to set Cloud9 URLs to subfolder?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, node.js, aws-cloud9

I have installed an instance of [cloud9](https://github.com/ajaxorg/cloud9) on a webspace (CentOS 5). Installation was easy and it is running fine.

My hosting provider supports mod_proxy, thus I use a .htaccess to re-route the requests to node:

```
RewriteRule ^cloud9/(.*) http://localhost:3131/$1 [P]
```

In theory, this works. I can access it and the sent source is clearly cloud9. However, the page stays white and my JavaScript console shows me this error:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Looks like they are using require.js, which fails to load:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/require.js"></script>
```

It is trying to load it from `example.com/static/require.js` because it doesn't know that it is called through a proxy. What do I have to change so it will use `example.com/cloud9/static/require.js`?

I have not found anything in the configuration files, but it would be great if there is a solution that does not require me to modify any of cloud9's code.